# Displaying image in a CGridView column

Tags: yii, yii-components

Here is my code

```
$img= Yii::app()->params['questionImageUploadURL'].$model->q_type."/".$model->qImgRel->image_name;
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'q_nationality_id',
        'q_type',
        'q_name',
        array(
            'name'  => 'q_image_id',
            'value' => (is_object($model->qImgRel)?CHtml::image($img,""):""),
            'visible'=>(is_object($model->qImgRel)?true:false),
        ),
        'opt1',
        'opt2',
        'opt3',
        'opt4',
        'answer',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Its display me like this
[image]

I dnt get image in my view
plz help me
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I got solution 'type'=>'raw' should be written

Comment: you can always answer your own question, and mark it accepted

Answer (score 2):

Try this  :-

```
 array(
            'name'  => 'q_image_id',
            'type'  => 'raw'
            'value' => (is_object($model->qImgRel)?CHtml::image($img,""):""),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<? php

$w="50px";$h="50px";

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'redcliffe-cms-grid',

    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),

    'filter' => $model,

    'columns' => array(
        'title','date','description',

       array(
            'filter' => '',
            'type' => 'raw',   
            'value' => 'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl ."/upload/" .$data>image,"",array(\'width\'=>\'50\', \'height\'=>\'50\'))', 
             ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
             ),
    ),
));
? >
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
                array(        
                 'name'=>'filename',
                 'value'=> CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/path/'.$model->filename),
                 'type'=>'raw',
            ),
```

would do the trick (don't forget the type 'raw')